# How to read url's, payload,headers from postman exported collection in rest assured

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to read the urls, headers, payload of collection of api's that are exported from postman collection and want to run in rest assured

I have tried to add json file to the project and call that file with name in the rest assured code but that was not working